# Finding the area under curve without using rectangles

Tags: integration

We all know that the area under a curve between two points a and b can be found out using rectangles. We can very well approximate it using rectangles that is the Riemann sum. But what if we use something else. What will happen if we use circles . How will we find the area and also is there any other shape which will give a better approximation than rectangles?

Comment: Optimal approximate curve depends on the function you are integrating, but ultimately shouldn't matter as you tend towards infinitesimal divisions of your domain.

Comment: You definitley can, for instance simpson's approximation uses parabolas to approximate the integral. Its also a better approximation than rectangles.

Comment: Only for parabolas but I want something general which will hold good for all functions

Comment: @sayan chattopadhyay actually Simpson's method works with every integrable function, non only with parabolas

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay As the width goes to zero, it does not much matter what we choose as function. $ \int y dx $ is the simplest, computation speed can improve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use circles.
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx={{b-a} \over n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(f \left(a+{b \cdot k \over n} \right)\right)$$
The above uses rectangles, to use circles, make their diameter d be equal to ${1 \over n}$ and have there be $$number=floor \left({f \left(a+{b \cdot k \over n} \right) \over d} \right)$$ 
circles, which is the number of circles that can stack on top eachother from the origin to the function height. The area of the circle is $\pi \cdot d^2/4$. Multiply this by the number of circles. Putting everything together...
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx={d \cdot (b-a)} \sum_{k=1}^{floor({1/d})} floor \left({f \left(a+{b \cdot k \over n} \right) \over d} \right) \cdot \pi \cdot d^2/4$$
as d approaches $0$ from the right, this becomes equal to the rectangle sum.

Comment: i want something that approximates better than rectangles

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay You specifically said that you wanted to see what would happen if you used circles. In addition, I already said you could use parabolas as a better approximation.